# Show that $(1-i)^{7}=8(1+i)$

Tags: complex-analysis

Homework Problem: Show that $(1-i)^{7}=8(1+i)$ by converting to polar form, taking the seventh power, and then converting back to standard form. Here is what I have:

$r=\sqrt{2}$ and $\theta=\arctan{(-1)}=-\frac{\pi}{4}$, then $(\sqrt{2})^{7}e^{-i7\pi/4}= 8\sqrt{2}e^{i3\pi/4}=8\sqrt{2}(\cos{(\frac{3\pi}{4})}+i\sin{(\frac{3\pi}{4})}=8\sqrt{2}(-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}+i\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2})=8\sqrt{2}(-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}+i\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}})=8(i-1)$.

I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong. My assumption is that I am not handling the argument correctly. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: $-\frac{7\pi}{4} = -\frac{8\pi}{4} + \frac{\pi}{4} = -2\pi + \frac{\pi}{4}$.

Comment: $e^{-i7\pi/4}$ is $e^{i\pi/4}$.

Comment: How did  you get $-7\pi/ \aprox 3\pi/4$?  Think what $-7\pi/4 + 2\pi$ is.

Comment: I was being stupid. I added $\pi$ and forgot the "-".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$e^{-i7\pi/4}$ is $e^{i\pi/4}$.